# .NET swagger leave out property from example value

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

**Is there a way to exclude/remove properties from your example value?**

I'm using XML comments on my models to provide information on the swagger page with `c.IncludeXmlComments`
I use the `///<example>Example Value</example>` *XML tag* to set the example values. My request model does not require all the fields to be set by default, but if I don't set an example *XML tag* the example value is translated to it's type. Looking like this

```json
{
  "ID": "string",
  "ExampleSetValue": "Example Value"
}
```

And I want my example value to only contain the ExampleSetValue property so my example value looks like this

```json
{
  "ExampleSetValue": "Example Value"
}
```

This is the swagger setup in my startup

```cs
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", openApiInfo);
    c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", openApiSecurityScheme);
    c.AddSecurityRequirement(openApiSecurityRequirement);

    // Set the comments path for the Swagger JSON and UI.
    var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
    var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);

    c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
});
```

My Request Model

```cs
public class CreateRequest
{
        /// <summary>
        /// ID of the user if available
        /// </summary>
        public string ID { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// ExampleSetValue
        /// </summary>
        /// <example>Example Value</example>
        public string ExampleSetValue { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code of your request model?

Comment: Can you also provide some mode context about your use case? Do you want to exclude the `ID` property from all request/response examples in all endpoints that use this model? Or only from some places but not others? For example, if you have GET and POST endpoints and you want the `ID` property to appear in GET responses but not in POST request body, the solution is to annotate the `ID` property as read-only.

Comment: I updated my question with the request model. I want to create examples specific to an endpoint. The ID value is optional but I don't want it to be in my example value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a different approach which suited my case exactly how I wanted.
You can set an example object on your schema which is of type OpenApiObject.

I Created a Document filter to which loops over the schemas in my swagger.

```cs
public class AddExamplesFilter : IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {
        foreach (var schema in context.SchemaRepository.Schemas)
        {
            schema.Value.Example = ExampleManager.GetExample(schema.Key);
        }
    }
}
```

Created the ExampleManager class which returns the example object I want according to the schema name.

```cs
public static OpenApiObject GetExample(string requestModelName)
{
    return requestModelName switch
    {
        "ObjectExample" => ObjectExample.GetExample(),
        _ =>  null
    };
}
```

And as the final step created an example class which corresponds exactly on how I want my example to look like. Where I used the OpenApiObject class

```cs
public static class ObjectExample
{
    public static OpenApiObject GetExample()
    {
        return new OpenApiObject
        {
            ["ObjectInsideObject"] = new OpenApiObject
            {
                ["Name"] = new OpenApiString("name"),
            },
            ["ArrayWithObjects"] = new OpenApiArray
            {
                new OpenApiObject
                {
                    ["Object"] = new OpenApiObject
                    {
                        ["integer"] = new OpenApiInteger(15),
                    },
                    ["Description"] = new OpenApiString("description")
                }
            },
            ["date"] = new OpenApiDate(new DateTime().AddMonths(1)),
            ["Description"] = new OpenApiString("description"),
        };
    }
}
```

**Final look on Swagger page**
[image: Swagger page]

Answer (score 1):

Xml comment seems cannot be used to exclude the property.

If you want to ignore the property, I suggest you use the `[System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore]` attribute. But in this way it will also make your property hidden when you serialize or deserialize the data.

```
public class CreateRequest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// ID of the user if available
    /// </summary>
    [JsonIgnore]                   //add this..........
    public string ID { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// ExampleSetValue
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>Example Value</example>
    public string ExampleSetValue { get; set; }
}
```

If you only want to exclude the property from example value, you need custom ISchemaFilter:

Model:

```
public class CreateRequest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// ID of the user if available
    /// </summary>
    [IgnoreDataMember]               //add this..........
    public string ID { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// ExampleSetValue
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>Example Value</example>
    public string ExampleSetValue { get; set; }
}
```

Custom ISchemaFilter:

```
public class MySwaggerSchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        if (schema?.Properties == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        var ignoreDataMemberProperties = context.Type.GetProperties()
            .Where(t => t.GetCustomAttribute<IgnoreDataMemberAttribute>() != null);

        foreach (var ignoreDataMemberProperty in ignoreDataMemberProperties)
        {
            var propertyToHide = schema.Properties.Keys
                .SingleOrDefault(x => x.ToLower() == ignoreDataMemberProperty.Name.ToLower());

            if (propertyToHide != null)
            {
                schema.Properties.Remove(propertyToHide);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Register the filter:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    //......
    c.SchemaFilter<MySwaggerSchemaFilter>();
});
```

Comment: Your answer pointed me in the right direction. Your approach worked, but it also removed the property from my Schema which I did not want. I still want my user to see all the properties available on the object. I posted my answer below how I only targeted the example.